# extract doubel quoted values from a string in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

The below is the string stored in a cell A1

`AND(filter(OR(authorizedorgtypes:string("Issuer/Acquirer"),authorizedorgs:string("SOFTBANK PAYMENT SERVICE CORP"))),filter(authorizedcountries:string("JAPAN")), filter(authorizedvbls:(string("IA"))))`

need formula to extract the values enclosed in double quotes in the above string.

output should be:

```
Issuer/Acquirer
SOFTBANK PAYMENT SERVICE CORP
JAPAN
IA
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so these should work provided you want each result in a different cell.

```
=MID(A1, FIND("authorizedorgtypes",A1)+27, FIND(")",A1, FIND("authorizedorgtypes", A1))-3-FIND("(", A1, FIND("authorizedorgtypes", A1)))


=MID(A1, FIND("authorizedorgs",A1)+23, FIND(")",A1, FIND("authorizedorgs", A1))-3-FIND("(", A1, FIND("authorizedorgs", A1)))

=MID(A1, FIND("authorizedcountries",A1)+28, FIND(")",A1, FIND("authorizedcountries", A1))-3-FIND("(", A1, FIND("authorizedcountries", A1)))
```

This is a little different because of the way the parentheses work in the last instance;

```
=MID(A1, FIND("authorizedvbls",A1)+24, FIND(")",A1, FIND("authorizedvbls", A1))-FIND("(", A1, FIND("authorizedvbls", A1))-10)
```

Its a total hack job but it works.